# Documents presented in the airport

Tags: paperwork, filipino-citizens, tpe

I am a Filipino working in Taiwan and am planning to visit Dubai. My husband has send me a visit visa and e-ticket.

What do I need to present in Taiwan airport, anything more than passport, visit visa and ticket?

Comment: What do you mean by "cross country"?  What are your flights?

Comment: I am a Filipino passport holder. I am working here in Taiwan. Now, I have a plan to exit dubai. From Taiwan to Dubai.

Comment: I don't have flight yet.  I need more info before I book a ticket.

Comment: Not Yet. My question is the list of  documents presented in the airport before going to travel.

Comment: I don't have a problem about the ticket

Comment: @JudeRomanoBarredo Are you returning to the Philippines on your way to Dubai?  There are no direct flights from Taiwan to Dubai, so you will need to change planes somewhere, and that place may require a visa or other documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The following will be required:

1. Visa Copy.
2. Passport that's valid for 6 months past your stay in Dubai.
3. Ticket (e-ticket or paper ticket).

Once you arrive in Dubai, simply follow the line to the immigration counter and present your visa along with your passport.